# How to replace unwanted items in a string with blank in stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

> JSESSIONID=655885676C46C0A9A00EDSRFA764016643FD; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 28-Nov-2014 16:42:52 GMT; HttpOnly; USER_ID=rC4tHFvd+DRcSRsk1jAsfd7Ag--; Expires=Wed, 27-May-2015 04:42:53 GMT; Path=/; USER_CONFIRM=47ead7afca94f5d5f8sera40e67f59fe526; Expires=Wed, 27-May-2015 04:42:53 GMT; Path=/; RCC_COOKIE=1417149773308/131490892; Path=/; CODE=bs8RT$Sxr1jrI+efnVq4pIV6CQ--; Path=/; Secure;  Expires=Mon, 11-Apr-2016 04:42:53 GMT; Path=/; SC=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/;SYN_COOKIE=x%2FWhJoldsfdgfrwRn227tbcNKKtCSjsAc7EYvvvSQPL1ou%2B0pLGmndZtzpb5cWrLKmSuWtAz4BJgB2RLGVnW%0Agm2u88liSw%3D%3D; Expires=Wed, 27-May-2015 04:42:53 GMT; Path=/; RCC_COOKIE=1417149773755/131490892; Path=/; SYN_COOKIE=x%2FWhJowRn227tbcNKKtCSjo0xOS1STGF6m63ovQlPDhbCh%2BmndZtzpb5cWrLKmSuWtAz4BJgB2RLGVnW%0Agm2u88liSw%3D%3D; Expires=Wed, 27-May-2015 04:42:53 GMT; Path=/;RCC_COOKIE=1417149774517/131490892; Path=/

This I'm extracting to a variable in style sheet

How to use regexp to remove Path, Expires , etc and other values whatever I wish

Like I just want to send only `JSESSIONID`, `SYN_COOKIE`, `RCC_COOKIE`, `CODE`. So I need to extract them only from this.

Comment: "*How to use regexp*" There's no regexp support in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about the regexp, but you can use the `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions of XPath.

Then, for exemple, this XPath below :

```
 substring-before(substring-after(.,'JSESSIONID='),';')
```

applied in context of your string (usage of the `.` xpath axis), will give you the 'value' of JSESSIONID.